# Using interfaces instead of concrete data structures in Java Collection API

Tags: java, collections

I am currently reading "Core Java for the Impatient" by Horstmann (I recommend it, love the concise style) and I have a trouble understanding one of the exercises pertaining to the collection API. The exercise is as follows:

> I encouraged you to use interfaces instead of concrete data structures, for example, a 
>   `Map` instead of a `TreeMap`. Unfortunately, that advice goes only so far. Why can’t
>   you use a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>` to represent a table of contents?
>   (Hint: How would you initialize it?) What type can you use instead?

The following code compiles and works without a problem though, even though the interfaces were used for variable declarations. What am I missing?

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> toc = new HashMap<>();
toc.put("element1", IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
toc.put("element2", IntStream.of (3, 4, 7).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
toc.forEach( (k, v) -> {
    System.out.print(k + " ");
    v.forEach(val -> System.out.print(val + " "));
    System.out.println();
} );
}
```

Comment: The use of interface-type variables to hold references to subtypes is not new, but it is the topic of the question. It's been a feature of Java since the beginning, so the age of the book is not an issue.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm baffled too, because you can. To answer the question in the quote, you'd initialize it using `new TreeMap<String, Set<Integer>>()` (or `new TreeMap<>()` if Java 7+), and create the value using `new TreeSet<Integer>()` (or `new TreeSet<>()`). I'd say Horstmann is wrong, but without full context he might have meant something else.

Comment: I think the question from the book is trying to make the point that you can declare a variable to be of an Interface type, but you can't instantiate an Interface: you have to instantiate a class that implements that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got in touch with book's author and he agreed that question was unclear and it was to lead the reader to use wildcard types. The exercise in question was changed to:

> Suppose you have a method parameter of type `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`, and someone calls your method with a `HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>`. What happens? What parameter type can you use instead?

The answer is that in this case one should use the wildcard type: `Map<String, ? extends Set<Integer>>`.

Comment: And do you understand why `HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>` wouldn't work? Hint: [Is List a subclass of List? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)

Answer (score 1):

An interface like `Map` is a supertype for all interfaces that inherit it and all classes that implement it. So `TreeMap` inherits from `Map`, and because you can always assign to a variable any reference that is of a subtype, it's perfectly acceptable to assign a `TreeMap` reference to a `Map` variable. This is called a *widening reference conversion*
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5
"Widening reference conversions never require a special action at run time and therefore never throw an exception at run time. They consist simply in regarding a reference as having some other type in a manner that can be proved correct at compile time."

So, yes, you certainly can use a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>` to represent something in your domain model, but you can't instantiate an interface directly; you must instantiate a concrete type (class) that implements it. This is exactly what you did when you declared
`Map<String, Set<Integer>> toc = new HashMap<>();`

As an extension of this principle, you could just as easily write 
`AbstractMap<String, Set<Integer>> toc = new HashMap<>();`
since `AbstractMap` is also a supertype of `HashMap`.

In general you want to declare the widest type for the variable that can hold the largest possible set of subtype references that work in your logic. If you need a sorted map, then 'Map' is too wide; it doesn't enforce sortedness. You'd have to declare the variable as `TreeMap` , or better, `SortedMap` for that.

Usually the interface is the widest applicable type, but you have to think about it in case it's not.

EDIT: Mentioned `SortedMap` in light of comment.

Comment: There is a `SortedMap` interface you could use instead of `TreeMap`.